# Display images into dynamic table

Tags: javascript, image, cell

I have a table which is generated based on user input to a form. That generates rows and cols. I want the nodes to be filled with an image. I am getting the table but nodes are filled with [object HTML image element]? I thiink this is trying to access the image but failing? Here is what I have tried. All help appreciated.

```
   for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
        col = row.insertCell(-1);
        img=new Image();
        img.src="../www/images/TEST.png";
        col.appendChild(document.createTextNode(img));
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just pasting the actual text of what the image object contains, which is definitely not what you want to do. Try something like the following.

```
img.onload = function() { //check to make sure that the image has loaded
    col.appendChild(img);
};
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks Nile. Tried to vote up but no reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), this is one of the solutions

in html :

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

in js :

```
var table = $('<table></table>');

for (r = 0; r < howOften; r++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (c = 0; c < numDays; c++) {
     row.append('<td><img src="../www/images/TEST.png" /></td>');
    };
    table.append(row);
};

$('#container').append(table);
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be posting jQuery for a question that didn't specify or imply jQuery